# Android : androidx.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException on any view of a layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

In my espresso test case checking

```
onView(withId(R.id.myRecyclerView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

is  giving the exception androidx.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id: com.xxx.xxx.debug:id/myRecyclerView' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.

How is it possible to have multiple instances of the recyclerview itself in the hierarchy.

the layout structure is:

```
`<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:visibility="condition here"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomButtonsContainer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/contents"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lead_details_spacing"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/lead_details_spacing">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:overScrollMode="never"
                        android:contentDescription="test"
                        android:visibility="condition"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            </FrameLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How to fix this exception?

### EDIT

I went through the log in details. What I see is that under view hierarchy

`Problem views are marked with ‘****MATCHES****’ below. View Hierarchy:` the whole layout is coming two times.

Flow:
Home -> tabs activity -> tab2 the layout with recyclerview mentioned above in the issue -> a button click on this layout takes to another activity X -> come back to tab2 -> verify content of recyclerview with espresso

When I first land on the tab2 fragment, I am able to perform click on the button. But when I come back to tab2 from activity X and try to press click again, I get the same AmbiguousViewMatcher Exception. So the whole layout is somehow getting duplicated. I tried inspect layout and there I dont see any duplicates. Any pointers on what could be going wrong?

Comment: I think there should be more in the error log, it should print out the other ambiguous view, and allow you to debug further.

Comment: yeah I went through the logs, it lists the whole layout two times!! If I were checking on any view in that layout ( that layout has recyclerview, Imageview and a button) it gives the same exception.

Comment: I am maybe making things up, but if you think that there shouldn't be duplicate views, then I guess there's something wrong with the source code. Is your tab view using a view pager with fragments, and how does the adapter look like? Are your fragments being added instead of replaced when the tabs are switched?